# Use from_dict() to initialize a subclass of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, inheritance

I know that inheritance is [not the simplest alternative](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/internals.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) when using pandas, but I'm curious as how to obtain the result I wish for.

Say I have a function that from a string returns a dictionary (the string could be a path, the name of a collection...):

```
def str_to_dict(string):
   ...

dic = str_to_dict(s1)
dic
>>> {'col_1' : ['a','b',...], 'col2': [1, 2, ...]
```

What I want to do is to create a subclass of `pandas.DataFrame` that would contain the data of `dic` while being initialized by a string using the method above *and retain the string as attribute.*

I know that simply passing a dictionary into `pandas.DataFrame` would work for some cases, but I might need to  change the orientation (keys being the index instead of the columns names), so I wanted to use the `from_dict` constructor to get my DataFrame.

Here is my work on it:

```
# Works but only if you want the keys of the dictionary to be the columns
class MySubClass(pandas.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, string):
         self.my_string_attribute = string
         dic = str_to_dict(string)
         pandas.DataFrame.__init__(dic)

# Does not work, throws a RecursionError 
# It is because __init__ is used with the from_dict constructor and calls itself
class MySubClass(pandas.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, string):
        self.my_string_attribute = string
        self.from_dict(str_to_dict(string)) # Here I could add any option needed
```

Once again, I know there are alternatives to inheritance and I might go with composition to carry on on my project, but I am just curious on how could it be possible to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why what you are trying to doesn't work is elaborated here:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2859

> And this won't work because it does not return an instance of your
>   subclass. (Bunch of issues here):
>
> ```
> # Works but only if you want the keys of the dictionary to be the columns  
> class MySubClass(pandas.DataFrame):
>     def __init__(self, string):
>          self.my_string_attribute = string
>          dic = str_to_dict(string)
>          pandas.DataFrame.__init__(dic)
> ```

So what you can do is add capabilities to pd.DataFrame class like this:

```
import ast
def str_to_dict(string):
    return ast.literal_eval(string) 

class MySubClass(pd.DataFrame):
    def from_str(self, string):
        df_obj = super().from_dict(str_to_dict(string))
        df_obj.my_string_attribute = string
        return df_obj

data = "{'col_1' : ['a','b'], 'col2': [1, 2]}"

obj = MySubClass().from_str(data)

type(obj)
# __main__.MySubClass

obj.my_string_attribute
# "{'col_1' : ['a','b'], 'col2': [1, 2]}"
```

[image]

Comment: It does in fact returns the object that I need, however it does not seem to retain the my_string_attribute ... If I try obj.my_string_attribute, I will get an AttributeError

Comment: @LoicM changed the way I initialize the df. It retains the `my_string_attribute` now.

Comment: Amazing ! That does exactly what I wanted to :) thanks !